# Order of coefficients in polynomial linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, polynomial-math

I'm building a simple polynomial model in Python using sklearn. My training set consists of 3-feature vectors (i.e. RGB triplets). I'm fitting a model using the following code:

```
degree = 1
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), Ridge())
model.fit(samples, y)

coef = model.named_steps['ridge'].coef_ 
intercept = model.named_steps['ridge'].intercept
```

All good using a one degree polynomial. This is the output:

```
Coefficients = [[ 0., -0.1235785, 0.8367021, -1.71648988]]
Intercept = [ 9.15605047]
```

In order to evaluate a new triplet with the model I just trained I could make use of:

```
prediction = model.predict(aNewTriplet)
```

Alternatively, I could do:

```
prediction = intercept + (-0.123578 * aNewTriplet[0] + 0.8367021 * aNewTriplet[1] - 1.71648988 * aNewTriplet[2])
```

What about if I have a second order polynomial (which outputs an array of 10 elements)? How would the coefficients be ordered? Like this?:

```
coefficients (order = 2) = [ 0, R, G, B, R^2, G^2, B^2, RG, RB, GR]
```